# TCPDF: Images aren't showing in PDF properly

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

Ok, I have a code to display the images on the same form

Like `formid=7` has two images and it shows both when I run the same query on the web page. But when I am applying same in PDF (TCPDF) It's showing just one image I dunno why

Code:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submits'])){
 require_once 'includes/practice.php'; 
 $pdf->SetFont('times', '', 10);
​ ​​$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 12);
​ //$pdf->SetTopMargin(5);
​ //$pdf->AddPage('L','A4');
​ include('connect.php');
​ $emp_number=$_POST['emp_number'];
​ $formid=$_POST['formid'];
​ //$image='<span><div> <h2>Shop Images:</h2></div>';
​ //$getFiles = "SELECT * FROM inspection_files where formid=$formid";
​ $getFiles = $link->query("SELECT * FROM inspection_files WHERE formid=$formid");
​ if($getFiles->num_rows > 0){
​ while($row = $getFiles->fetch_assoc()) {
​ ​   $imageURL = 'images/'.$row["file_name"];
​    $images='<img src="'.$imageURL.'" width="150" />';
​   }
​ } else {
​  echo '<p>No image(s) found...</p>';
​ }
```

Somewhere down in HTML I've requested `formid` like `$_REQUEST['formid'];`

Comment: Change `$images =` to `$images .=` . It's overwriting your image in each step

Comment: How do you add the images to the PDF? You're looping through the query results but don't appear to be doing anything with them.

Comment: @crazyloonybin Its  not a complete code... Adding to PDF is by writehtml defined for pdf

Comment: @ArmKh sure lemme try and get back

Comment: As @ArmKh pointed out, you're overwriting the image in each iteration of your while loop. You can either do what they suggest and append the image details each time, or you can add the `writeHTML()` call into the while loop.

Comment: @crazyloonybin writehtml in while I can't cuz its printing whole pdf one time.. Other option sure lemme try and come back Thanks

Comment: @ArmKh but one confusion why on web page it shows result correct for both images by $images if its over writing? Cuz issue is only coming in PDF not web page

Comment: @IqraKhan , are you using the same `while` loop in the web page as well?

Comment: Yes @ArmKh infact I copied same query and code for displaying

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean - you can call `writeHTML()` multiple times, then you call `Output()` right at the end once you've finished creating the PDF. As for the webpage showing both images, I'm assuming you've got something along the lines of `echo '<img src="'.$imageURL.'" width="150" />';` in the while loop?

Comment: Have you tried the change? Is it working?

Comment: @crazyloonybin I copied exact same code from web page to PDF but on web both images shown against form id .. I tell you scenario actually..two tables t1 t2 suppose t1 has formid and t2 has formid I am viewing all records from t1 by select * but images i am getting against same formid column but from t2 as t2 has images only. Like each record 2 images it has. On web page php it shows correct two images on pdf display only one shows

Comment: Something must have changed between the webpage and PDF versions. The PDF version in your question doesn't have anything for printing out the images at all (e.g. you have the `echo '<p>No image(s) found...</p>';` in the else clause, but there's nothing to print the actual image itself). Either something has changed between the two versions, or you're not showing us all of the relevant code.

Comment: Yes u r right @crazyloonybin I was on web page saying echo 'img src and for PDF now followed $image. as said by ArmKh and worked.. Thanks so much to you too

Comment: Can u guide i am getting images like this not inline one line I need side by side Thanks Screenshot here https://prnt.sc/pzwxkw

Comment: @crazyloonybin 
Can u guide i am getting images like this not inline one line I need side by side Thanks Screenshot here prnt.sc/pzwxkw – I even have Posted new thread too abt that

Comment: @ArmKh
Can u guide i am getting images like this not inline one line I need side by side Thanks Screenshot here prnt.sc/pzwxkw – I even have Posted new thread too abt that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `$images` variable is being overwritten in each loop step.

Try to change this row in a while loop

`$images='<img src="'.$imageURL.'" width="150" />';`

to this

`$images.='<img src="'.$imageURL.'" width="150" />';`

Comment: worked thanks mistake was the same yes in web I was using just echo 'img src etc

Comment: Cool. Happy coding :)

Comment: Can u guide i am getting images like this not inline one line I need side by side Thanks Screenshot here https://prnt.sc/pzwxkw

Comment: Can you Pls guide about Screenshot I uploaded even have Posted new question too regarding the same Thanks